# Transimpedance Amplifier Not Outputting Voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode, transimpedance

I'm trying to build a transimpedance amplifier to convert the current from my photodiode to a voltage that can be read using an ESP32. The components I am using are:

- OPA170AIDRLT Operational Amplifier ([link](https://www.ti.com/product/OPA170/part-details/OPA170AIDRLT))
- QSB34CGR Onsemi Photodiode ([link](https://www.digikey.co.za/en/products/detail/onsemi/QSB34CGR/3904985?s=N4IgTCBcDaIIoGUBCBmALAYQOICUQF0BfIA))
- 97.6kΩ Resistor
- 0.15uF Capacitor

I designed my circuit based on the Texas Instruments guide ([link](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa268a/sboa268a.pdf)), and my circuit looks like the following schematic:

[image]

Like the title says, I am not measuring a voltage output from my circuit. More specifically, I am measuring 0V. I have checked the resistance over the photodiode to see whether it is in working order, and it is. Unfortunately, my circuit is soldered onto a PCB, so measuring the current output from the photodiode will not be very easy and I am leaving it as a last resort. Am I missing something obvious? What tests can I perform to find out what is wrong with my circuit? My lack of experience with this type of circuit is currently my downfall, so I would greatly appreciate any help or advice!

Comment: it is better to use a TIA with the photodiode operating in the photoconductive mode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Am I missing something obvious?*

Yes, your photodiode is connected the wrong way round.

When light hits it, photocurrent will flow from 0 volts to the inverting input of the op-amp and, to maintain a virtual ground, the op-amp output would need to drop to a negative value on its output but, it can't do that because you have a single supply configuration.

Here's how it's normally done with a single rail op-amp and ground referenced photodiode: -

[image]

Image from [Photodiode Amplifier Design using Photodiode Wizard - CN-0312 Spectroscopy Example](https://ez.analog.com/design-tools-and-calculators/w/documents/3605/photodiode-amplifier-design-using-photodiode-wizard---cn-0312-spectroscopy-example) supplied by Analog Devices (a very useful web page).

Comment: If the photodiode absolutely *needs* a grounded cathode, then adding a DC negative supply voltage to pin 2 (Vee?) is an option. Detected light will cause a negative-going output voltage from the opamp.

Comment: I suspect that a 3.3 volt rail is used so that a positive output is desirable for feeding into an ADC input (that probably can't cope with negative voltages).